# Adding projects to a project in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm developing an application that uses [Managed WiFi](http://managedwifi.codeplex.com/). Normally I would just add the .dll to the project, but this library comes as a regular VS project. How do I use it in my program? I tried adding Interop.sc and WlanApi.cs to my project, but WiFi classes are not recognised.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add the ManagedWifi project to your solution and then reference if from your main project (Add reference → Projects tab).

Answer (score 8):

Visual Studio works with [solutions and projects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2015/ide/solutions-and-projects-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2015). You want to add your Managed WiFi project to your existing solution

[image]
<sub>(source: [ranorex.com](https://www.ranorex.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/add_existing_project-546x263.png))</sub>

and then reference that project from your own project

[image]
<sub>(source: [programming4.us](http://programming4.us/image/022011/Creating%20a%20Component_3.jpg))</sub>

Answer (score 3):

If you do not need to modify the source code of this managed wrapper. Just open the project in a separate Visual Studio and build it, grab the output library and add it to your project.

Answer (score 1):

Add it to your solution by clicking File | Add then select existing project.

Find the .csproj file and select that. This will add it into your Visual Studio solution.

In the project you want to use this new project, right-click References and Add reference. You can then select the new project and it will be usable in your main project now.