# How to access a static class in same namespace but another assembly?

Tags: c#, wpf, namespaces

I am working with a WPF application in C#.  I have a number of constants defined in a static class as the following:

Project1:

```
namespace MyCompany
{
   public static class Constants
   {
      public static int MY_CONSTANT = 123456;
   }
}
```

Then all I need to do to access my constant anywhere inside Project 1 is:

```
int x = Constants.MY_CONSTANT;
```

Now I add another project to the same solution, and use the same root namespace:

Project 2

```
namespace MyCompany.MyControl
{
   class VideoControl
   {
      int x;
      x = Constants.MY_CONSTANT; //<-- doesn't work
      x = MyCompany.Constants.MY_CONSTANT; //<-- doesn't work either
   }
}
```

I just can't figure out a way to access my static Constants class from the second assembly.  I also can't add a reference to the first assembly, because it leads to circular dependency (the second project assembly is a WPF control used by the first project assembly).

Is what I'm trying to do even possible?  Currently my workaround is passing all the required constants in constructor, but I'd rather just access them directly.

Comment: You need a reference - you'll need to resolve your circular dependency - maybe move the constants class out into a 3rd assembly which both other assemblies can reference.

Comment: beside the point: if you want a constant, why don't you declare it as a constant `public const int MY_CONSTANT = 123456;`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can move all of the static constants from project 1 to project 2, therefore, all of the constants are visible to both project 1 and project 2;
I recommended that introduce another project (maybe common) which could help to manage all of the stuffs that shared by all of the other projects. it's a common infrastructure project.

Comment: I'll accept introducing a 3rd assembly as an answer.  For some reason I figured as long as I am in the same namespace I don't need references.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a reference in Project 1 to Project 2, then it should work just fine. Do you need a graphic to illustrate how?

Here's an MSDN link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky.aspx

And here's an SO answer with pictures> [Adding projects to a project in Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6237580/adding-projects-to-a-project-in-visual-studio-2010)

Comment: Project 1 is a WPF project that uses a WPF control inside Project 2, so I'm pretty sure it references it already.  Unfortunately my code is at work, so I won't be able to double check till tomorrow.  Will get back to you then.

Comment: Well it's kind of odd to ask us to help you figure it out when you can't check it ;-)

Comment: I was working from memory, since the problem has been bugging me at home.  Just checked and yes Project 1 does have a reference to Project 2.

Comment: And where is the class you need to reference, since the other poster brought it up? Are you about to engage a circular reference?

Comment: remember that references are sort of like one way pipes, you can bring _from_ the referenced class, but don't create a cycle.

Answer (score 0):

The other answer is close, but it's actually the reverse: Project 2 needs a reference to project 1. The code should then compile.

EDIT:

Sorry, I see that you've already considered this. Yes, someone commented to avoid a circular dependency issue by introducing a third assembly.

Comment: To me the difference between "Project 1" and "Project 2" is merely directionality. Had he given names, such as "AutoManufacturers" and "CarDealerships" I could have been more explicit. Please do not confuse generically non-directional names to imply intent, but look for the intent inherent in the example, such as the linked question which showed referencing one project from within another.

Comment: Sorry, it's the first question I asked on StackOverflow, and I was trying to keep code as generic as possible to make it easier to parse.  Looks like in the end I cut it down too much.

Comment: Feel free to be highly explicit in the future, without violating NDAs.